# Can't open bitmap file using default program

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have a form which has a TImage component on it that displays images from a directory. Clicking the TImage component opens the file using its default program.

For example, clicking a `jpeg` image file will launch it into windows photo viewer.
For some reason when clicking a bitmap image file it doesn't open, it doesn't do anything.
Opening the file outside the program just through windows does open it via windows photo viewer.

Below is the code for what I'm doing when clicking the TImage component.

```
procedure TfrmCase.ImageClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShellExecute(Handle, 'open',PChar(filen), nil,nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;
end;
```

Comment: Try to check if the `filen` variable contains the fully qualified file name (and  try to use a default verb `''` instead of `'open'`, but that should not be a problem here).

Comment: I can confirm that the variable 'filen' is looking at the correct file name

Comment: what is the result of ShellExecute function ? IF that is failure - what is windows error code ? dig around APIs like http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.SysUtils.Win32Check

Comment: Run SysInternals Process Monitor and intercept your program's file and registry I/O, make a log starting with the click and ending with the return to the program after failed attempt to run the program. Save those logs for both JPEG and BMP, then compare and look where they took different turns.

Comment: @Arioch, `ShellExecute` does not use `SetLastError`.

Comment: Maybe using `ShellExecuteEx` (note the "Ex") gives better error messages.

Comment: @TLama, I think default verb should be `nil` not `''`. Dag, You need to check the return value of `ShellExecute` to find out what went wrong.

Comment: You're ignoring the return value of ShellExecute. Why do so many people do that? In this case you should never call that function. Ever. Call ShellExecuteEx. It reports errors in a sane manner.

Comment: @TLama okay, I screwed on this detail, the general idea holds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have known what was wrong if you had done error checking as David suggested.

Check the following code:

```
uses
  WinAPI.ShellApi;

procedure TForm22.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Command: string;
  Info: TShellExecuteInfo;
  MyFilename: string;
begin
  MyFilename:= 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oobe\Background.bmp';
  FillChar(Info,SizeOf(Info),#0);
  Info.cbSize:= SizeOf(Info);
  Info.fMask:= SEE_MASK_DEFAULT;
  Info.lpFile:= PWideChar(MyFilename);
  Info.nShow:= SW_NORMAL;
  //Info.lpVerb:= 'open';  
  Win32Check(ShellExecuteEx(@Info));
end;
```

This works just fine with the default verb.

The info for `ShellExecuteEx` is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Always remember to zero the record `FillChar(Info,SizeOf(Info),#0);`, because the stack can and does contain random garbage.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that's why I suggested checking the registry. However running the above code will generate the proper error and from there the OP can diagnose. Will elaborate in the answer.

Comment: Your code is broken though. You've not fully initialised the SEI struct

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Sorry yes, you need to zero out the struct before using it obviously.

Comment: It was because .bmp file type doesn't have a default program associated with it, I had to correct this in control panel > folder options. This is still weird because I could open the file normally outside the program. Thank you for your time everyone.

Comment: OP says: "Opening the file outside the program just through windows does open it via windows photo viewer" so, how is that possible?

Comment: @Dag I have some free advice for you. Don't dwell on the mundane details of the associations on your machine. The thing that you really need to take away from this is the lesson that you have to implement error checking when using Win32. If you don't learn that, then you are doomed to keep asking variants of this question forever.

Comment: if `bmp` was not associated, Windows would have asked you to choose a program. not open it via a photo viewer. maybe registry was corrupted.  strange...

Comment: @Johan: Explorer does not use the `open` verb directly. It uses `ShellExecute()` with a `nil` verb so the default verb is invoked correctly, whatever it happens to be.  When `ShellExecute()` is given a `nil` verb, it uses the default verb if registered, otherwise it uses `open` if registered, otherwise it uses the first available verb. This is documented behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to say is that you are not checking for errors. This is a common mistake which we observe many times a day here. Perhaps you are used to exception based error handling. But Win32 does not throw exceptions. Error checking must be explicitly coded.

In this case you need to check the return value of the function. However, `ShellExecute` is obsolete and has been replaced by `ShellExecuteEx`. Only the latter is capable of proper error reporting.

So, you must check for errors as described in the documentation. Call `ShellExecuteEx` and test the return value. If it is false then the function failed. If that occurs call `GetLastError` for extended information.

Once you've added proper error checking you'll be on the way to working out what went wrong in this case.